# Installing Node.js with OpenSSL on Amazon EC2

Tags: openssl, node.js, make

I am trying to set up a new Amazon EC2 instance (never done it before) and I'm stuck at getting Node.js working with OpenSSL.

First I installed it without OpenSSL just to see if I could, works fantastically.  Then I went back and downloaded OpenSSL 1.0.0d (marked as `latest`) and ran `make` and `make install` and it ran fine, but then I went back to run `make` on Node again and I get this message:

```
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib
Checking for g++                         : ok
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib
Checking for gcc                         : ok
Checking for library dl                  : yes
Checking for openssl                     : not found
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : not found
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : not found
/opt/node-v0.5.0/wscript:319: error: Could not autodetect OpenSSL support. Make sure OpenSSL development packages are installed. Use configure --without-ssl to disable this message.
```

That's the exact same message I got before I did a successful install of OpenSSL 1.0.0d.

I am an amateur at linux in knowledge but feel comfortable enough in it.

Ran `make test` on OpenSSL and got `All tests successful`

Comment: I think it might have something to do with libssl-dev?  It's a prerequisite but I have no idea how to see if it is installed and I don't have apt-get to install it (in fact I don't even know what version of linux my ec2 instance is using)

Answer (score 2):

Believe I figured it out.  Amazon EC2 instances are running on CentOS which uses `libssl-devel` vs `libssl-dev` (notice the `el` at the end of the first one).

Looks to be working on the `make` correctly now!